# How to replace text in edit area with a button, that has a function on click to add to url a text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a plugin button created on a bar in tinymce editor in moodle
I need to make this plugin button to do this: replace selected text in edit area with a button, name of the button should be as replaced text was. Then i need this button to  have a function to play audio with that link : http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=TEXT , where TEXT = replaced text

generaly clicking tinymce plugin button supposes to convert written sellected text to a voiced button, that uses google service to voice that text.

part that i am missing is code for plugin. Here what i have found so far, see example what it does http://jsfiddle.net/bXsWQ/137/:

```
function replaceSelection(html) {
var sel, range, node;

if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    // IE 9 and other non-IE browsers
    sel = window.getSelection();

    // Test that the Selection object contains at least one Range
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        // Get the first Range (only Firefox supports more than one)
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        // Create a DocumentFragment to insert and populate it with HTML
        // Need to test for the existence of range.createContextualFragment
        // because it's non-standard and IE 9 does not support it
        if (range.createContextualFragment) {
            node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        } else {
            // In IE 9 we need to use innerHTML of a temporary element
            var div = document.createElement("div"), child;
            div.innerHTML = html;
            node = document.createDocumentFragment();
            while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
                node.appendChild(child);
            }
        }
        range.insertNode(node);
    }
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    // IE 8 and below
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML(html);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not clear what you need here. Please simplify your question to just the specific problem.

Comment: Why have you add jquery tag to the question but you don't use jQuery lib in your code ?

Comment: 2Roberto, Feel like it might be needed here, might need to delete if dont

Comment: 2Isherwood, specific problem is that i dont know how to make second and third part of my task work. Now it replaces a text with a button, but button needs to be named with text it replaced. And onclick function of this new button should add that text to a link i posted, so final product would be a button that user can click and it pronounces text the button replaced.